# Does $\exp(X)$ commute with $X$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If I have a real invertible matrix $X$ and I take the matrix exponential of this matrix $Y = \exp(X)$, are there any reasons for $X$ and $\exp(X)$ to commute? Obviously if $A$ and $B$ commute then so does $\exp(A)$, $\exp(B)$ but this doesn't help much.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$e^X = \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}X^n$ is a power series, and each term commutes with $X$. By continuity, the limit of the power series commutes with $X$.

Comment: of course. Thanks